# Como puedo agregar en la clase

Tags: c++

estoy haciendo una clase

```
template<typename T,int ... num> 
class A{
private: 
vector<T>}
```

donde ingrese en el main

```
A o={1,2,3}
```

como hago para que funcione y o se guarde completamente en la clase

Answer (score 0):

Cuando quieres que las clases hagan algo al construirse, debes redactar su constructor:

```
template <typename T, int ... num> 
class A
{
public:
    A() : valores{num ...} {}
//  ^^^ <--- constructor por defecto;


private: 
    std::vector<T> valores;
};
```

Si le añadimos las funciones de iteración, podemos ver el contenido del objeto creado:

```
template <typename T, int ... num> 
class A
{
public:
    A() : valores{num ...} {}

    auto begin() { return valores.begin(); }
    auto end() { return valores.end(); }

private: 
    std::vector<T> valores;
};

int main()
{
    A<int, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9> a;

    for (const auto &v : a)
        std::cout << v << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes verlo funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9dasQgFIWfvas4UOjMgA0tpZQmIZA9zAYcYwchUfEnUELWnupMhr70RbjHz@N3pXMvchTmum1P2sgxDQqttiF6JaaO/rJZyWh9RxTV5EYRcxR/nDJiUjhzaBNRVRVMmjpQbgwBPS3k0mXUsibWH0@oMYvRehWWjBV8xbISMZGixUVdtcnQAq9i8ubBVvtFg3UnlRn@425xoch5PWfDGsRCHOr67t6euwfb0NoQFedJlO4syvo2zxxvHO8cHxyfHF8dRObYt/U4SmtCxE3gec6riBOxe720KaJtMZfjgEN5sru95p@27Rc)</kbd>.

Comment: Creo que la elipsis está demás y que él quiere poder asignarlo con un arreglo o tener un list initializer

Comment: Y llegas a esa concusión porque... (desarrolla tu respuesta).

Comment: Porque en la pregunta indica que en el main quiere ingresar `A o={1,2,3}`. Suele pasar que quien pregunta tiene una idea pero no sabe bien cómo resolver e incluye algo que distorsiona la pregunta.

Comment: Pero podrías concluir que lo que quiere es una clase plantilla (pues lo escribió primero) y lo de "ingresar de tal manera en el `main`" es la distorsión ¿no?

Comment: Cierto. Tocará esperar para saber qué es lo que realmente quería.